# Tax estimates for 1099 without withholding

Tags: united-states, taxes, banking, virginia

I'm married and the sole-provider for my household which includes three children. I contract for The Palladium-item and made $11,556.00. I am self-employed, so I was paid through a 1099. I drove about 12,000 to 14,000  miles last year.

How much taxes will I pay for federal and state? Can I take deductions for mileage? I would like to know if you can give me a rough estimate of the amount I would get.

Comment: Is that _all_ of the income you have or just _extra_ income?  The amount of tax will depend on what tax bracket you're in.

Answer (score 4):

As you did not provide the info I cannot comment on your state tax liability.

With the income you indicate, you are just better off doing a 1040EZ.  Your tax liability will be zero from your income.  Up to and including $20,700 is tax free if you are married and filing jointly, you earned significantly less than that.

Additionally, you will be provided $508 from the Earned Income Credit benefit. So it pays for you to file as soon as possible.  The sooner you file, the sooner you will have $500 in your pocket.

A number of sites will allow you to file a 1040EZ for free and will offer you your refund now as opposed to waiting a short time (typically less than 2 weeks during this time of the year).  I would advise against this as the fees for this short term loan are an effective predatory interest rate.

**EDIT:**  OP said he had three children after an edit to the original question.  He'll have to a 1040A, and the work won't be much different then a 1040EZ.  However, with the amount of kids he would have gotten more money from the EIC had he earned more.

Comment: can you file a 1040EZ with 1099-MISC income?

Comment: I believe so.  The checklist from the instructions does not exclude 1099-MISC.  Additionally the form says 1099 on line 7.  Even if he had to a 1040A form, it would not be much more work then the EZ.

Comment: Most of the online prep's are free for 1040EZ and even 1040A.  If it were me, I'd punch it into my favorite one and see the tax implications.  Then file if it is free to efile or if I am willing to pay the efile fee.

Comment: Nitpick: new this year (due to a recent law) IRS will hold refunds for returns with EITC or ACTC until after Feb. 15, so filing before that won't get the money sooner (although it will get your filing out of the way). They have issued numerous notices on this, due to its obviously wide impact; the most recent one (currently on the homepage) is https://www.irs.gov/uac/newsroom/irs-answers-common-early-tax-season-refund-questions-and-addresses-surrounding-myths

Answer (score 0):

Since you have added the state tag since Pete B. wrote his answer, I'll answer the state income tax portion.

> How much taxes will I pay for federal and state?

According to [Virginia](http://www.tax.virginia.gov/content/who-must-file) you must file if you earned over $23,900, which you did not. So you should not have to pay any state taxes. It's worth filing if Virginia offers any credits that you qualify for. You can find the list [here](http://www.tax.virginia.gov/content/tax-credits).